# Rotate part of custom multipart shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I want to create a custom node shape that eventually looks like this:

[image]

It’s easy to draw a TikZ picture that renders the above, using multiple nodes. However, I want it to be a single node, so that I can use the `forest` package to draw trees made of these nodes. And also, I got curious ;-)

After reading the PGF manual, my impression is that this can be accomplished with a custom shape with five parts: (1) text: *“Lorem ipsum…”,* (2) label: *“all”,* (3) id: *“12345”,* (4) hello: *“hello world”,* (5) value: *“4/5”.*

I started with just the text (*“Lorem ipsum…”*) and the label (*“all”*) part and already ran into problems. The following code is my attempt.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\newsavebox{\pgfnodepartlabelbox}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{mynode}{
    \nodeparts{text,label}

    \savedanchor{\northeast}{
        \pgf@y=1.\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox
        \advance\pgf@y by -0.\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox
        \pgf@x=1.\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
        \advance\pgf@x by \wd\pgfnodepartlabelbox
    }

    \savedanchor{\southwest}{
        \pgf@y=-.0\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox
        \advance\pgf@y by -1.0\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox
        \pgf@x=.0\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
    }

    \savedanchor{\joint}{
        \pgf@y=0pt
        \pgf@x=1.\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
    }
    
    \anchor{label}{\joint}
    
    \foreach \anchor in {center} {%
        \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{\anchor}%
    }

    \inheritbackgroundpath[from=rectangle]
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [mynode, draw=red, text width=4cm, align=justify]
        at (0,0) {
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
            \nodepart{label}
            foo
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Above code outputs:

[image: Actual output without rotated label part]

But I want it to output (the colors and spacings don’t matter for now, I think I can handle these):

[image: Desired output with rotated label part]

So my questions:

1. Is it even a good idea to solve my problem with a custom multipart shape? Or should the other parts be somehow passed as options?
2. How can I rotate a single node part? The *“foo”* in my attempt is not rotated.
3. How can I define the text width of a single node part? The *“foo”* part is my attempt has a width of 4cm like the *“Lorem ipsum…”* part, but I only want the *“Lorem ipsum…”* to be 4cm.

Comment: I recommend using *like-node pic* as in this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/616995/140722

Comment: I don’t see how I can use *like-node pics* with the forest library. Maybe multipart nodes are not fit for my task. I might have to define all but the *Lorem ipsum…* text via options and do something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147141.