# Multimeter box with 4 nodes

Tags: circuitikz

This is what I am looking for, but can't seem to find it anywhere.

[image]

I found a way to make a [box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240670/how-can-i-add-a-box-in-an-electric-circuit), but can't seem to fit 4 nodes in there.

Isn't there a command for such a multimeter?

Can we do one with 4 nodes?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\standaloneenv{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american, cute inductors]
        \draw
        %%-----V in-----%% 
        (0,0) node[anchor = east] {C} coordinate (C)
        (0,2) node[anchor = east] {B} coordinate (B)
        (0,4) node[anchor = east] {A} coordinate (A)

        (A) to [short] ++(2,0)
        (B) to [short] ++(6,0)
        (C) to [short] ++(2,0)
        (1.5,0) to[short,*-] ++(0,1.2)
        to[short] ++(1,0) 
        to [short] ++(0,-.2) node (rectangle) [draw, rectangle,anchor=north west] {HI \quad A \quad LO};
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}   
\end{document}
```

I can make a box, but I'm unable to write in it as per the figure, and attach my wire as per the drawing.

Comment: It will help if you show the code that you already have and explain what you want to add/modify.

Comment: Thanks for adding some code. Could you make it compilable, please?

Answer (score 2):

This is not as convenient as the built-in items, but `pic`s are relatively easy to create and can be made rather more complex than `node`s, which may be helpful here. (A node might be preferable, but would require you to drop to the lower-level commands and specify everything in PGF.)

[image: <code>pic</code> <code>multimeter</code>]

The code uses a `name=<name>` key to work around one of the bugs in the current implementation of `pic`s. This means that naming `pic`s with the natural `(<name>)` syntax doesn't work. (The `seagull` example from the manual fails to compile, for example.) Since this has been broken for a while, convenient workarounds are the order of the day.

The `fit` library is used to draw the enclosing box after the 6 internal nodes are constructed.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\standaloneenv{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  pics/multimeter/.style={
    code={
      \tikzset{
        multi meter/.cd,
        #1,
      }
      \begin{scope}[]
        \coordinate (\multimetername-o) at (0,0);
        \foreach \i/\j/\k/\l in {A/o/south/A,V/o/north/V,TL/mA.west/east/HI,BL/mV.west/east/HI,TR/mA.east/west/LO,BR/mV.east/west/LO} \node (\multimetername-m\i) [multi meter/label, anchor=\k] at (\multimetername-\j) {\l};
        \foreach \i in {TL.west,TR.east,BL.south,BR.south} \node [circle, fill, inner sep=1.25pt] at (\multimetername-m\i) {};
        \node [draw, fit=(\multimetername-mTR) (\multimetername-mBL)] {};
      \end{scope}
    }
  },
  multi meter/.search also={/tikz,/circuitikz},
  multi meter/.cd,
  label/.style={font=\sffamily, align=center, transform shape, pic actions},
  name/.store in=\multimetername,
  name=multimeter,
}
\begin{circuitikz}[american, cute inductors]
  \draw
  (0,0) node[anchor = east] {C} coordinate (C)
  (0,2) node[anchor = east] {B} coordinate (B)
  (0,4) node[anchor = east] {A} coordinate (A)
  pic [rotate=-90] at (3,0) {multimeter={name=M}}

  (A) to [short] ++(2,0)
  (B) to [short] ++(6,0)
  (C) to [short] ++(2,0)
  (1.5,0) to[short,*-] ++(0,1.2)
  to[short] ++(1,0)
  -| (M-mTL.west)
  (M-mBR.south) to[short] ++(-1.25,0) coordinate (c) to [short,-*] (B -| c)
  ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your answer seem good, but I can't make it run on Overleaf, I have an error stating (no shape name pgfextra9254start is known). I assume it as something to do with the "pic", but I don't know how you coded this, do you know whats going on ?

Comment: Do you know what version of PGF/TikZ OverLeaf has? `pic`s have been around for a bit, but they were only introduced in version 3 so maybe OverLeaf has an older version such as 2.1?